# Why is making variables public visibility a bad practice

Tags: java

I am in a Introduction to Java class and I was doing a bit of research on variables.  It seems that knowledgeable programers state that it is bad practice to define the variables in public visibility.  I see them stating it is bad practice but I can not find a rhyme or reason to their claims.  This is how I defined my variables in a application for my course.

```
public class DykhoffWk3Calculator 
    {
        /*
        * This class is used to define the variables in a static form so all 
        * classes can access them.
        */
        public static double commissionRate = .03, startSalary = 45000,
                accelerationFactor = 1.25; 
        public static double annualSales, commissionTotal, totalCompensation,
                total, count, count2;
        private static Object input; Object keyboard;

public static class UserInput
    { //Then continue with my other classes
```

I thought this was a logical method of defining them so all classes, not just main, could access them.  Can someone explain to me why this is bad practice, and where variables should be defined?  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Public visibility, not "in a public class".

Comment: Variables should only be initialised/created in their retaliative scope - since they use memory and so it uses more memory than required.

Comment: Theire is a difference between `a variable in a public class` and `a public variable in a class`

Comment: FWIW, they aren't variables. They're called "[members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.2)" (specifically, in your case, the usual term would be "class data members" or "static data members"). Variables are those things you use within functions (or initializer blocks).

Comment: @SamDufel Thank you for setting me straight on that. That makes more sense that it is public visibility.

Comment: @jhamon Yeah, I understand that now.  Is it better practice to make a public variable in a class?

Comment: If you read the answers, you will find out it's better practice to make variables `private` in your classes

Comment: @jhamon Yeah, it is starting to sink in.  Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In short: because all of your public "surface area" for a class effectively defines its API.

If you expose things through methods, then you can change the details of how they work later.  But if you expose a field, and some other class outside of your control (and quite possibly outside of your knowledge) starts referencing that field, then you're stuck with exposing that field for the rest of time.  Or until you decide to break backwards-compatibility.

> I thought this was a logical method of defining them so all classes, not just main, could access them.

As a general rule, you don't want "all classes" to access them.  The vast majority of work with software, is spent maintaining code, not writing it for the first time.  And so experienced developers realise that best practices for code, are generally the ones that make it most maintainable, not necessarily the ones that make it most convenient to write in the first place.

And if you have a variable that could be accessed from anywhere, at any time, and you want to make some tweaks to how it is modified - how can you be sure that this is safe?  How long will it take you to track down all the ways that this is referenced, and determine what the effects of your change will be?  (And specific to public fields, you can kiss goodbye to any sort of reusability regarding running at the same time from multiple threads, or running reentrantly.)

Broadly speaking, reducing the "surface area" of classes is a really good thing to do.  Restricting the ways that other classes can interact with this one, makes it much easier to control and understand the relationships, as well as making it easier to make internal changes "invisible" to those other classes.  Think about what this class *does*, what it will provide to other classes, as defining an interface (whether an actual `interface` or not).  And only expose to other classes, the bare minimum that is required to fulfil those requirements.

And that never involves letting them have arbitrary access to variables.

Comment: I think you need to mention the solution to not having public fields is to provide getters and setters.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! You really assisted in helping me understand why this is not a good thing to do.  I understand now that outside entities can change these variables, even if you did not intend them to.  Thank you again!

Comment: @dkatzel I wouldn't even be that prescriptive.  As I mentioned near the end, one should think about what conceptual operations/functions that you want this class to provide - and then do whatever is necessary to provide those.  So if it makes sense to expose some property through a getter, then you should define a getter.  But I don't think one should do this willy-nilly, if it's not actually necessary.

Answer (score 1):

So the general point is that you in fact DON'T want anyone to be able to access those values. Not only can I see those variables, but I can also change them to anything I like. This can lead to problems in larger, more complex programs.

Furthermore, if you wanted to later change how the class uses/stores these values, you couldn't without having to go out and change all the other classes that access those public variables directly. Instead, you should offer methods that provide just the amount of access that you want to give.

The standard analogy is that of driving a car. You know how to turn the wheel, hit the brake, etc, but not how the car actually does these things. So if the engine needed to be dramatically changed, or you got in a new car, then you'd still know how to drive. You don't need to worry about what's happening behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

Public variables in general in a class are a bad idea. Since this means other classes/programs, can modify the state of instances.

Since it is the responsibility of a class to protect its state and ensure the state is "consistent", one can enforce this by defining public setters (since this allows to run code to check/repair state).

By setting the variables public, the state is not protected. If later not all representable states are valid states, one has a problem.

**Example**:

Say you want to implement an `ArrayList<T>`, then it will look like (not fully implemented):

```
public class ArrayList<T> {

    public int size = 0;
    public Object[] data = new Object[5];

}
```

Now one can modify the `size` of the arrayList. **Without** adding an element. Now if you would ask the `ArrayList<T>` instance to remove/add/copy/...whatever, the data on which it works can be wrong.

Perhaps you can claim that a programmer is nice: he will not modify the object unless he needs to and according to the "rules". But such things eventually always go wrong, and what if you decide to modify your definition of the `ArrayList` (for instance using two `int`'s for the `size`). In that case you would need to rewrite all code that sets such fields.

To conclude: `private`/`protected` is invented to **protect** a class instance from other instances that would turn the instance corrupt/invalid/inconsistent/...

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you state it wrong.

its bad to make your variable public i.e:
`public String name = null;` this is bad. You should always do it as
`private String name = null;`

To understand why, you need to dig a bit into the ideology of OOPs
OPPS ideology states that each object of your class will have 2 things:

- Properties: something which we also call variables or state.
- Behavior: something which we call methods or functions.

Properties identify the object over a period of time. Behaviors allow you to manage the properties of the object so that the same object over time can appear to be in different states.e.g: a Product object over a period of can be an 'Available line item' or 'Added to cart' or 'Sold' or 'Out of stock' depending on its state. Since state is critically important to the object so the object should not allow direct nonsense mutation operations on its state. Objects should keep their variables private to them and expose behaviors that the outside world can use to interact with the object and change the state based on the operation executed in the behavior. e.g: calling the 'addToCart()' behavior on the Product object that was in 'Available line item' state would probably mean: changing not just its state to 'Added to cart' but probably making other users aware that the number of this Products now available is 1 less.

So long story short: don't expose properties directly to outside work for mutation unless needed. This means dont make them public and also dont give setter methods if not needed.

Answer (score 0):

By Convention Fields, methods and constructors declared public (least restrictive) within a public class are visible to any class in the Java program, whether these classes are in the same package or in another package.Which means that a change in the value of a field will definitely affect other classes accessing that field..thus breaking the whole sense of encapsulation.